# CanvasJS graph cannot find $ in fetching data-code

Tags: javascript, json, canvasjs

I am busy trying to generate real-time data, for this I am using the services of CanvasJS as they have pretty awesome graphs.

I have my JSON data fetch code, I have my html code where the graph will be rendered in. But it won't show the chart.. So I opened Inspector in my webbrowser to see where or what the problem is this is what I get as an error:

> [Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
>     global code (myHeart_Chart.html, line 7)

The code I have now:

**myHeart_Chart.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

                $.getJSON("data.php", function (result) {

                var dataPoints = [];

                for (var i = 0; i <= result.length - 1; i++) {
                dataPoints.push({ x: Number(result[i].x), y: Number(result[i].y) });
                }

                var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                data: [
                {
                dataPoints: dataPoints
                }
                ]
                });

                chart.render();
                });
        });


</script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width:100%;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP to return JSON data:

**data.php**

```
   <?php
    //header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","WebApplication");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to DataBase: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    } 
    else
    {
    $data_points = array();

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM info");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {        
        $point = array("x" => $row['id'] , "y" => $row['acceleration']);

        array_push($data_points, $point);        
    }

        $json =  json_encode($data_points, 32); //define('JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK',32);   // Since PHP 5.3.3
        $json = str_replace("\"", "", $json); //replace all the "" with nothing
         echo $json;

    }
    mysqli_close($con);

    ?>
```

the php first generated this:

> [{"x":"1","y":"5"},{"x":"2","y":"5"},{"x":"3","y":"4"},{"x":"4","y":"1"},
>   {"x":"5","y":"8"},{"x":"6","y":"9"},{"x":"7","y":"5"},{"x":"8","y":"6"},
>   {"x":"9","y":"4"},{"x":"10","y":"7"},{"x":"14","y":"7"},{"x":"15","y":"7"}]

Then I added this line:

```
 $json =  json_encode($data_points, 32); //define('JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK',32);   // Since PHP 5.3.3
            $json = str_replace("\"", "", $json); //replace all the "" with nothing
             echo $json;
```

so that the output will be numbers:

> [{x:1,y:5},{x:2,y:5},{x:3,y:4},{x:4,y:1},{x:5,y:8},{x:6,y:9},{x:7,y:5},{x:8,y:6},
>   {x:9,y:4},{x:10,y:7},{x:14,y:7},{x:15,y:7}]

Furthermore:
basically line 7 is the part where it says:

> $(document)

** I have been busy with this canvasjs for about 3 weeks now.. I don't think I know what to replace document with.**

Comment: Well, you haven't loaded any script that would define a `$` variable, so that's the expected result.

Comment: Can you perhaps elaborate on that with some simple example please?

Comment: nevermind I think I know what to do, thanks anyway.